# I would like to write Script to write Script on the scripting white board

Tags: android

I am trying to make a scripting tool that would bring up text buttons such as " button script view" . When clicking on this text, in a frame below it would add the script " Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button); ". This app would be a little cheat sheet short cut to programming making it a tad easier than typing every durn thing over and over , now you have a click to write scripter. when your whole script was done, you then could copy and paste whole script into your aide program or whatever program you use.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you don't need to cast a view nowadays. Also there are tools like butterknife and even native view binding: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding